# npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-sass

I'm trying to install the following library in my react app: react-awesome-loaders.
However when i try to install it i get this error:
`npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.`

my node-sass verison is: 6.0.1

my node version is 15.6

I have removed package-lock.json and node_modules and cleared npm cache, and then installed the packages again but that didn't help.

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your sub-dependencies is trying to install node-sass 4.14.1, which isn't supported by Node 15.

PS: Node 15 is end of life, but you may need to go to Node 14, if you need to install node-sass 4.14.1

Comment: @nschnni do you know Any  hack to install  node-sass 4.14.1 on node 16 ?